# Google Maps Blank but still has location on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, swift4

I have been trying just about every tutorial I can find but I have no luck rendering the google map tiles behind the map in the view. I have double checked google console etc. But I have no luck

As you can see I can get the location to load up correctly, but the actual map behind it doesn't work at all. I have run out of ideas :(

[image]

Comment: Did you check it on device?

Comment: check console probably api key not correct and have some permission denied

Comment: Yep that was the answer, just worked it out I had to enable it on the console

Answer (score 0):

### try

- check it on real device
- double check that API Key of google maps correct and you enable google maps form google console
- self.view = mapView in didLayoutSubView Method